# how to add mod security exception

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, mod-security, mod-security2

I have installed Mod Security using the following instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-modsecurity-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-debian-8

It seems to be working fine, but I don't seem to be able to create exceptions for example for the WordPress login. I have added the following to my virtualhost file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public_html/wp-admin">
    <IfModule security2_module>
        SecRuleEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I have also tried the following:

```
<LocationMatch "/wp-admin">
    <IfModule security2_module>
        SecRuleEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

And different combinations of both.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 but I guess it's the same as for 14.04, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ModSecurity runs at several different phases. The first phase runs before any Directory or Location rules are processed. So turning ModSecurity off like this just won't work as by the time Apache gets round to processing that config it will be too late.

The better way to do this is to write a ModSecurity rule to "allow" these locations:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /wp-admin" "phase:1,id:12345,allow"
```

Or alternatively dynamically turn off ModSecurity for the rest of this request (which will have basically the same effect as above):

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /wp-admin" "phase:1,id:12345,ctl:ruleEngine=off"
```

It's important that either of these rules is defined **before** any other rules, to ensure the other rules don't block requests before the above rule(s) take effect.

However I would say that wp-admin is one of the most likely attack locations on a WordPress site so note sure why you would go through the hassle of installing ModSecurity and then decide not to protect that particular URL with it!

Comment: Where to I enter these rules? To answer your question: I have PHP max upload set to 128mb, but ModSecurity only allows for 12mb, so I would like to make an exception there. I would also like to make exceptions for tools like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Anywhere in your Apache config after your main ModSecurity config. Really recommend you read this to understand ModSecurity better: https://www.feistyduck.com/books/modsecurity-handbook/

Comment: On cPanel/WHM, you can go to WHM > Modsecurity Tools > Rules List > Edit Rules, and paste the above code right into the textarea. Restart Apache to deploy the new rule. It works like a charm.

Comment: @BarryPollard Do you instead have a resource that doesn't cost money and provides a quick and to the point answer to the question at hand?

Comment: Can you please define what your issue is and why the free answer to the question raised by the OP was not sufficient? There are a number of questions and answers on Stack Overflow (many written by myself) about adding ModSecurity exceptions but the OP specifically asked about turning it off completely for certain URLs - which is what I answered.